# USB Termination Resistor

Tags: usb, atmel, termination

I am using the Atmel AVR32 UC3C AT32UC3C2512C for a project and the datasheet doesn't say anything about terminating the USB connection, but the AVR32768 Application note, clearly points out a 39 ohm termination resistor (page 13).

Is it a problem if I left the PCB with no termination resistors at all?

I will connect this USB to another and make an extension so I don't know how this will influence the impedance of the traces and deal with this resistor. (I am new to Signal Integrity and High Speed Signals, but I know the basic theory already).

Comment: this links are very useful..  1)http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-5052.pdf 2)http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/usb%20line%20termination%20_ag.pdf this 4th paragraph lot of information regarding the allowed rise times. read usb2.0 specification electrical specifications. i recommend to have series termination for the prototype. I didn't understand what is meant by extension in ur post..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a prototype I built I made the same mistake. I got away with it with a short USB cable (0.5m) but when I tried a long one (3m) I could not get it to work reliably.

Needless to say the production units have these resistors and work reliably with both long and short cables.

Comment: Good to know it! Which MCU did you use to make the USB connection? And did you use 39ohm resistors as well?

Comment: @mFeinstein I was using an ARM processor with USB built in: LPC2148.  Note: the impedance includes the output impedance of the USB chip (in my case processor); Use the value recommended by the manufacturer.  In my case it was 39 ohm and yes I have them fitted.